JAX-RS Resource Not Found (404) When Running on Open Liberty
I'm working on a Maven project that uses JAX-RS to create RESTful web services and deploys them on Open Liberty. Despite configuring my application, I keep encountering a 404: SRVE0190E: File not found error when trying to access my REST endpoint.
My project is structured as follows:

pome.xml
     <!-- JAX-RS API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serverName>guideServer</serverName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
<plugin>

HelloWorld.java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String greeting() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

MyApplication.java
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}

My server.xml includes the following:
<featureManager>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
    <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<application id="jaxrs-liberty" location="jaxrs-liberty.war" type="war"/>

I build the project using mvn clean package and run the server using mvn liberty:run.
When I navigate to http://localhost:9080/jaxrs-liberty/api/hello, I get a 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /api/hello.
What might be causing my JAX-RS resource not to be found, and how can I resolve this issue?
